# Git cloneの挙動がおかしい

Tags: git

ローカル内でのクローンは問題なくできるのですが、Gitプロトコルで接続しcloneしようとするとなぜか変な挙動を起こします。

環境は・・・
≪リモートリポジトリの環境≫
OS：Windows Server (2007)
Git：2.16.2.windows.1
≪クライアントの環境≫
Git：2.17.0.windows.1

ケース1：リポジトリを作成した状態(容量：56K)　← NG

> $ git clone git://XXXXXX/sample2.git sample2222
>   Cloning into 'sample2222'...
>   fatal: read error: Invalid argument
>   fatal: early EOF
>   fatal: index-pack failed

ケース2：5回pushした状態(容量：71K)　　　　　 ← OK(5回以上であればいける)

> $ git clone git://XXXXXX/sample5.git sample555
>   Cloning into 'sample555'...
>   remote: Counting objects: 14, done.
>   remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
>   remote: Total 14 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
>   Receiving objects: 100% (14/14), done.

ケース3：かなり操作をした状態(容量：17M)　　　← NG

> $ git clone git://XXXXXX/copy.git copycopy
>   Cloning into 'copycopy'...
>   remote: Counting objects: 748, done.
>   remote: Compressing objects: 100% (412/412), done.
>   Receiving objects:  75% (561/748), 13.36 Mremote: Total 748 (delta 226), reused 684 (delta 211)
>   fatal: read error: Invalid argument13.36 MiB | 5.34 MiB/s
>   Receiving objects: 100% (748/748), 15.79 MiB | 5.38 MiB/s, done.
>   fatal: early EOF
>   fatal: index-pack failed

ケース1に関しては、調べてみても原因や対策がわかっていません。
ケース3に関しては、cloneする際に [--depth 1]をつければできましたが全ての履歴が欲しいときにどうすればいいかわからないです。

※Git初心者 かつ CVSしか利用したことないので、知識が乏しいです・・・。

Comment: 経験上、リモート通信がなんだかよくわからない挙動になったときは大抵、社内プロキシサーバやアンチウイルスソフトが理由だったりするわけですがそれはともかく。`-vv`オプションを付与して`git clone -vv git://XXXXXX/sample2.git sample2222` のようにとすると何か原因が分かりそうなメッセージは出力されるでしょうか。

Comment: 情報ありがとうございます。`-vv`オプションつけてみましたが、特に変わったメッセージでず・・・。`want b55b (refs/heads/master) done`の後にfatalメッセージが出ている感じです。。。社内プロキシサーバやアンチウイルスソフトが理由の場合、明確におかしなメッセージってでますか？？
`

Comment: すみません。追加で質問なのですが、HTTPやSSHにプロトコルを変更すれば解消されるとかっていう問題でしょうか？？※初歩的すぎてすみません

Comment: リモートリポジトリが「Windows Server」となっていますが、こちらは（GitHubなどではなく）自前で建てたサーバを利用しているということでしょうか。あとクライアント側のWindowsはどの種類（バージョン）をお使いでしょうか。

Comment: はい。[Windows Server上にGitリモートリポジトリを導入する手順書](https://qiita.com/nipoko/items/6e81a6021358ff8c03e9)を参考に建てました。クライアントは**Windows 7 Professional**使ってます・・・。

Comment: 個人的に、unix 自身にある程度詳しくない限り、 Windows の上で unix 系のシステムを動かすのはやめたほうがいいと思います。というのも、 Windows の上で unix のツールを動かそうとすると、サブunix システムのようなものを導入し、(今回なら msys)その上で動作させることになり、問題が起きた時には、 unix の問題と、そのサブシステム固有の問題両方を取り扱う必要があるからです。それは、割と大変です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

根本原因の解決とはなりませんでしたが、自分なりに結論付けました。

GitLabで上記ケースの再現をしてみたところ・・・

CASE１ ⇒ 問題なくクローンできる。
(GitLabではGitプロトコルではなくHTTP経由でのアクセスだからそれも影響している可能性がある？)

CASE３ ⇒ 問題なくクローンできる。
　　　　　(これに関しては設定な気がしています・・・。)

Gitでバージョン管理する場合、GitLabを利用するのが良いと判断しました。
(Gitサービスを利用することの方がユーザー管理やらメリットが増えますし・・・)

WindowsサーバーにGitをインストールしても動作面の不安定さ、その原因を調査するための知識の無さで諦めました・・・。

Answer (score -2):

gitは、Linuxを作った人が作成したものであるため、サーバー側のリモートリポジトリはLinuxの方が良いと思います。githubはプライベートだと有料ですので候補から外れていると推測します。可能であれば仮想環境としてLinuxを立ち上げ「gitlab」などで管理してみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: また、個人学習だと推測されますのでgitlab（インストールではない）であれば無料でプライベートリポジトリを利用することができます。（根本的な解決策になっていなくて申し訳ありません。）https://gitlab.com/users/sign_in

Comment: リモートリポジトリの問題ではない場合は、類似している以下の設定をしてみてはいかがでしょうか？https://github.com/Hacklone/private-bower/issues/54

Comment: +1. git 初心者であることを考慮すると、これはむしろ現実的な選択だと思います。

Comment: unix系知識が乏しくGitLab構築に高い壁を感じており、ネットで「Windows git リモートリポジトリ」で調べて結構情報でたので、安易にWindowsでリモートリポジトリー構築は普通にできるとおもっていましたが、それは**unix知識があること前提**だったのですね・・・。ひとまず質問内容は解決できませんでしたが、追求せず、GitLab構築に頭を切り替えようと思います。

Comment: すでにこの質問は解決済みとなっておりますが、もう一つの選択しとして、質問者様のような方でも簡単にgitlabなどをインストールできる「bitnami」というものがあります。Linuxに触る機会として、自信がつきましたら、検討してみてはいかがでしょうか。http://deadcode.hatenablog.jp/entry/2014/08/08/134914

Comment: 質問本文のエラーメッセージでウェブを検索してみるといくつか事例がヒットしますが、サーバ側は特にWindowsとは限らない様子です。プラットフォーム依存の可能性もあるかもしれませんが、安直に決めつけてしまうのは早計だと思います。

Comment: そうなりますと、GitLabを構築しても発生しうる問題ということですね・・・。ひとまずGitLabを構築し、Windowsで行った操作を実行しどのような結果になるか調査しようと思います。結果がわかり次第自分なりの結論をUPしようと思いますので、未解決に更新します